# access static class fields in android layout.xml

Tags: java, android, xml

I have `Constants` java class in my android project and I want to create a layout.xml.

In the xml file I want to access the `public static final` fields from my `Constants` class.

How can I do that ?

layout.xml

```
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=Constants.HelloMessage/>
```

Constants.java

```
public class Constants {
    public static final String HelloMessage = "Hello Dear Users";
}
```

Comment: First: There is a `strings.xml` in your values-folder. This does exactly what you want. Second: You can't access Code-Variables from XML. You'd have to set them manually at initialization of the activity, preferrably in the `onCreate`-Method.

Comment: @ManuToMatic are you advising me that I should move all my constants from the Constants.java class to strings.xml ?

Comment: @Oleg ...or programmatically assign them at activity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to manage string resources for Android is using the [string.xml file](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) in your res/values folder.

However you can also set the text of a UI widget programmatically if you need to. This would generally be used for dynamic text but there's nothing to stop you continuing to use static `String`s in your Constants class.

In the `Activity` or `Fragment` which inflates the layout containing, for example, your `RadioButton` above, you need to get a reference to it, and then set the text. To get a reference you'll first need to give the `RadioButton` an id in XML:

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radio_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And then programmatically set the text using the Constants string:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_button);
    radioButton.setText(Constants.HelloMessage);
}
```

A note on style, your string variable should be in [camel case](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm), so should be `helloMessage`.

Answer (score 3):

Change your xml to the following

```
<RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/radBtnId"
/>
```

In your java class,

```
RadioButton radBtn=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radBtnId);
radBtn.setText(Constants.HelloMessage);
```

Or else you can mention the String in strings.xml like to refer directly in xml file

```
 <string name="tag">Name</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `strings.xml` for this purpose. The way you are doing is wrong.

Go to res folder then to values>strings.xml. Open it and place your string there like

```
<resources>
    <string name="hello_message">Hello Dear Users</string>
<resources>
```

Then in your layout

```
<RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=@string/hello_message/>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: If I have ints or floats constants, should they be also put in the strings.xml ?
sounds kinda wrong

Comment: in strings.xml you only define strings. And ```android:text``` only accepts strings not int or floats

Comment: But every number can be represented as string @ZeeshanShabbir. You can define a string with the value `11`, for example.

Comment: So how should I call the ressource.xml file where I will store my numerical constants ?

Comment: No. You would have to represent your numbers as string in xml. But those will be treated as strings.

Comment: In simple words everything that you define in strings.xml will be treated as strings whether if it is number or character.

Comment: and they will be converted to my desired primitive type when I will use them...
If that's industrial code , than I'll do likewise :)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Integer maybe you can have a look at this on how to define integers

Comment: You would have to convert them yourself through code. But strings.xml is used for strings and ```android:text```  accepts only strings. You can also use integer.xml for integer. You can follow the link that nithish provided for detail guidenace